# Core Data Warning when saving child MOC

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am currently getting a lot of core data warnings in my app saying - `CoreData: error:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x608000661540, store PSC = 0x0)`. I am using a parent-child context relationship in the app, and I notice that the warnings always appears as soon as I call save on my child context.

I have been trying to look this up online and can't seem to find a fixed answer as to why this warning really appears. Some have said its because nil objects are being saved, but I printed out the objects just before the save call and all of them seem fine without any nil values. The application doesn't crash. I just want to get rid of the warnings.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957462/fetchedresultscontroller-swift-3-api-misuse-attempt-to-serialize-store-access-o

Comment: so I still run into this issue when I am using a view controller with more than one NSFetchedResultsController all using the same delegate. The only way to not get this error for this view controller is to save the MOC before performing a fetch on each NSFetchedResultsController. Is there a way to avoid saving before fetching every single time?

Comment: How are you building your core data stack and how are you creating the child context.